# Get another field value when setting dynamic data to another field

Tags: php, typo3

In flexforms, I have a dynamic field like:

```
<dynField>
    <TCEforms>
        <onChange>reload</onChange>
        <label>SELECT FOLDER</label>
        <config>
            <type>select</type>
                    <itemsProcFunc>tx_myext_fillBEData->fillFoldersField</itemsProcFunc>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</dynField>
```

It works good and I can actually put runtime values in there.
I set the onChange reload property to reload page when items changed for the next dynamic field to be loaded with values depending on current one.

The problem is I can't seem to get selected item from other field in order to fill data accordingly.

I searched a lot without any reference to that.

Any hint?

UPDATE 1: I can't use displayCond on the next field, as I simply can't know how many items I will get, so I can't code a generic XML with all positibilities and use displayCond.

UPDATE 2: So what I need is some way to get current selected value *inside* a function like tx_myext_fillBEData->fillFoldersField to get the new values with other field condition there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve that and I want to share it.
The $config parameter (first parameter) contains an XML which have the current flexform selected data.
You can access it via an array with:

```
t3lib_div::xml2array($config['row']['pi_flexform']);
```

This way we can gather the needed data:

```
public function fillFoldersField($config) {
    $piValues  = t3lib_div::xml2array($config['row']['pi_flexform']);
    if (is_array($piValues)) {
        $FieldData = $piValues['data']['SHEETNAME']['lDEF']['FIELDNAME']['vDEF'];
        //Inside FieldData we will have the selected data from any field we specified before
    }
    else {
        //An error, there is no data, for example, the first load, without user interaction
    }
    //Below this, we insert the other values
    return $config;
}
```